# mysql password special char limitation using via file

Tags: mysql, linux

My MySQL servers user name and passwords are root/test#123. I am using mysql 5.6.X. There is no restriction in the password length are characters.

My problem is, I can login directly from mysql client, as    `mysql -uroot -ptest#123` successfully.

But I am not able to login using    `mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/info.txt` .

Contents of "/tmp/info.txt" are,

```
cat /tmp/info.txt

[client]  
user=root  
password=test#123
```

I observes, it fails because of '#'. If I am using a different password without special char, the same works fine.

Could any one suggest me, how to handle this?

Also what are all the character like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to have been a bug [reported several years ago](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74482).  You could try putting the entire password into double quotes.

Comment: Add quotes to the ***password values*** whenever you are going to use # or any special character i.e `password="test#123"`

Comment: Thanks all of you. It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Represent the Password with in the double quotes will resolve this issue.

```
[client]  
user="root"  
password="test#123"

mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/info.txt
```

Also it is possible to define user name with in the quotes helps to avoid such a issues for user name.